# Is this a good way of using ViewModelLocator in MVVM

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, viewmodellocator

WE have a ViewModelLocater class in our Silverlight App. It consist of a basic constructor and  a public property to return the ViewModel for a class. The code is something like this

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private  Dictionary<string, ViewModel> _viewModels =
              new Dictionary<string, ViewModel>();

    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        _viewModels.Add("Home",  HomeViewModel());
        _viewModels.Add("Setup", new SetupViewModel());
        _viewModels.Add("TasksActivities", new TasksActivitiesViewModel());
        _viewModels.Add("Timesheet", new TimesheetViewModel());
    }

    public ViewModel this[string viewName]
    {
        get { return _viewModels[viewName]; }
    }
}
```

and in each of the XAML pages we set the ViewModel for that page using

```
DataContext="{Binding [Setup], Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
```

`Setup` is the key in the above dictionary.

The Silverlight App is really big and we have only recently started looking into any memory leaks(There are many...) I am using Windbg to track these leaks and I have noticed a lot of memory leaks leading back to the ViewModelLocater class. Every time the app loads the ViewModelLocator constructor creates ViewModels for all the Views. So I am wondering if there is a better way of implementing the ViewModelLocator class.

Comment: Can you not create viewmodels lazily (as and when required), instead of creating all upfront?

Comment: The ViewModelLocater class was created to give a dummy model for the design time. Each view creates a new instance of their viewmodel in their OnNavigatedTo event. Now I am new to MVVM and Silverlight and this ViewModellocater class was created by a previous seniorprogrammer. so I am not sure if this is the right way to create one.

Comment: We use ViewModelLoader/ViewModelLocator to provide both DesignTime as well as Runtime DataContexts. Our ViewModelLoader code would look like [this](http://ebook-management.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/SourcesProject/eLibraryCatel/eLibraryCatel/Factory/ViewModelLoader.cs) and all our ViewModelFactories will implement [IFactory](http://ebook-management.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/SourcesProject/eLibraryCatel/eLibraryCatel/Factory/IFactory.cs), With this way, you are only creating ViewModels as and when required, not all of them upfront.

Comment: Can you point me to an example?

Comment: Sample code is too big to post as a comment, so posted as an answer.

Comment: Even though your ViewModelLocater class was created to give dummy model for the design time, looks like for you, it is creating those instances at runtime, and you mentioned views again created their own ViewModels. That means, all the dummy viewmodels created by viewmodellocator are just hanging there, and hence you see leaks in that part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use ViewModelLoader/ViewModelLocator to provide both DesignTime as well as Runtime DataContexts.

**ViewModelLocator Class**

```
public static class ViewModelLocator
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FactoryProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Factory",
        typeof (IViewModelFactory), typeof (ViewModelLocator),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void SetFactory(DependencyObject dependencyObject, IViewModelFactory value)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(FactoryProperty, value);
    }

    public static IViewModelFactory GetFactory(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return (IViewModelFactory) dependencyObject.GetValue(FactoryProperty);
    }

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var fe = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe != null)
        {
            fe.DataContext = GetFactory(dependencyObject).Create();
        }
    }
}
```

**IViewModelFactory**

```
public interface IViewModelFactory
{
    object Create();
}
```

**ViewModelFactory**

```
public class MainViewModelFactory : ViewModelFactoryBase
{
    protected override object CreateDesignTimeViewModel()
    {
        return new MainViewModel(new DesignTimeEventAggregator(), new DesignTimeLogger(), new ViewModelViewRepository());
    }

    protected override object CreateViewModel()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
    }
}
```

**ViewModelFactoryBase Class**

```
public abstract class ViewModelFactoryBase : IViewModelFactory
{
    protected abstract object CreateDesignTimeViewModel();

    protected abstract object CreateViewModel();

    public object Create()
    {
        return Designer.IsInDesignTime() ? CreateDesignTimeViewModel() : CreateViewModel();
    }
}
```

And in XAML, this is how I hookup ViewModel Locator to View:

```
<viewModelLocation:ViewModelLocator.Factory>
    <viewModelFactories:MainViewModelFactory />
</viewModelLocation:ViewModelLocator.Factory>
```